# OS X Lion + PHP + PostgreSQL, pg_connect returns nothing

Tags: php, postgresql, osx-lion

I have to migrate a large PHP application with PostgreSQL database to Rails. This is OS X Lion Macbook Pro, using the existing installation of Apache + PHP.

I installed PostgreSQL via Homebrew. Let's say the host is "localhost", username is "my_username", default database is "my_db". Password is blank. Here's the result:

I can access the database just fine from the command line with

```
psql -h localhost -U my_username -p 5432 my_db
```

No problem. This also works:

```
psql -U my_username my_db
```

Also no problem. And I can get to the database also using Rails, quite easily, with these settings:

```
adapter: postgresql
encoding: sql_ascii
template: template0
database: my_db
pool: 5
username: my_username
password:
```

That all works fine. But in PHP, when I do

```
pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=my_db user=my_username") or die(pg_last_error());
```

I get this message:

```
LANG_FATAL_ERROR: LANG_DB_COULD_NOT_CONNECT
Access denied for user 'my_username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

And if I remove "host=" from the line, leaving:

```
pg_connect("port=5432 dbname=my_db user=my_username") or die(pg_last_error());
```

or

```
pg_connect("dbname=my_db user=my_username") or die(pg_last_error());
```

I get exactly nothing. pg_connect returns false, indicating no connection, but there are no errors! pg_last_error() returns nothing.

I also tried adding password='' to the connection string, without results.

I tried very hard to find any reference to this problem on Stack Overflow, Google, etc. and have had no luck. There are a couple of questions with similar titles on Stack Overflow but not this specific issue. All I've found on the 'Net was to compile pgsql.so for myself and make sure the extension is listed in php.ini. I have done that with zero results.

Obviously this is not a problem with PostgreSQL itself, but something having to do with PHP.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This error message:

> Access denied for user 'my_username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

is a well known **MySQL** error message, it's not related to the pg_connect() call.

Also note that pg_last_error() can't be expected to output anything useful for a connection failure because it assumes an existing connection. 
The error message related to the connection failure has to be searched in the PHP error output.

Comment: I am aware that this looks like a MySQL error message. But look again at the PHP: the function being called is pg_connect(). It has nothing to do with MySQL. I did eventually get this sorted out, though. Thanks for the try.

Comment: @LonnyEachus "I did eventually get this sorted out, though"... Sure would be nice if you would share with the rest of us! After all, that's what you're asking us to do, right?